# table-cell adapt to image

Tags: html, css

I have this problem. I need that the yellow div adapts to the contained image; its width is dynamic, so I can't use a fixed width.

[image]

I can't find a solution anywhere, and I've tried with `margin: 0; display:block;` but nothing.

Here is the code:

HTML

```
<div class="columna" style="max-width: 100%;">
    <div class="s_container seleccion_simple_default">

        <div id="text_opcion">
            <div class="ti-ab-d"  style="display: table-cell;">
                <label for="test" ><p>Prueba</p></label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ssm_opcion img_opcion">
            <img src="images/opciones/mcdonalds.png">       
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.s_container{
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: none;
    position: inherit;
    display: table;
}

.ssm_opcion{
    width: 1px;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background:yellow;

}

.img_opcion{
    display:;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.ssm_opcion img{
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#text_opcion{
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    min-width: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    display: table;
    float: left;
    background:green;
}

.ti-ab-d{
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```css
.s_container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  position: inherit;
  display: table;
}
.ssm_opcion {
  width: 1px;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: yellow;
}
.img_opcion {
  display: ;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.ssm_opcion img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#text_opcion {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 50px;
  text-align: left;
  display: table;
  float: left;
  background: green;
}
.ti-ab-d {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="columna" style="max-width: 100%;">
  <div class="s_container seleccion_simple_default">

    <div id="text_opcion">
      <div class="ti-ab-d" style="display: table-cell;">
        <label for="test">
          <p>Prueba</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ssm_opcion img_opcion">
      <img src="images/opciones/mcdonalds.png">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pasting your HTML and your CSS into a JSFiddle doesn't result in your screenshot; is there other CSS / HTML your snippets are missing?

Comment: I've added the class .ti-ab-d but thats just the orientation of the text in the green div

Comment: You have an unclosed `<label>` element in your code, please correct that (it should be corrected both here *and* in your live page); also please use an absolute URL to the image you use in your demo (or an appropriate substitute for that image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some conflicting CSS in the snippets you provide, I've modified the code to remove the `.img_opcion` CSS you had in there. Image autosizes to the container nicely.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lvv7Lxrs/1/

**EDIT**: the width declaration is just to prove the container snaps to size, as the default "broken image" browser stand-in is a bit small.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? No comment to tell me why? Giving the answer away, perhaps?

Comment: Yes, but you've put a fixed width. It has to be dynamic

Comment: I put the fixed-width in there to demonstrate it fitting the boundary. It works if you set the `width` to `auto` as well. And no worries, the downvote comment was a general question, not to you specifically :)

Comment: The image won't resize unless you set an explicit size on the image itself, or unless you set an explicit height on the parent container.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101093/discussion-between-polo-and-gorbles).

Answer (score 0):

If you add a div and in the div you put a paragraph inside the div, if you give to div such rules css a background-color: #color, the div fits automatically to the paragraph, you don't must you do not have mandatory put a width-height fixed.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to say here?

Comment: That you don't must always declar width-eight, if you add a text, the div will have a size of text.